# Inaccurate results when getting the user's screen dimensions for macOS

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

So I'm having an issue with retrieving the dimensions of the user's screen when running either a .NET MAUI or .NET MAUI Blazor app. I've tried 'DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo', but the dimensions for the Height and Weight are both inaccurate. I'm running the app in Visual Studio Community for Mac 2022, targeting MacCatalyst on a 2019 16 inch MacBook Pro running the latest macOS Sonoma. The dimensions should be 3072 × 1920. Yet 'DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo' is giving me a Width of 3584 and a Height of 2240.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tested on my side, and it will appear the issue that it cannot recognize the screen pixel well. You can report this issue on the GitHub.

Comment: Here is [Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809?locale=en_US) for the MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). The default is  3072‑by‑1920. And some other resolutions are also supported. I assume you have changed the resolution in Displays Settings.